# How to get screenshot to clipboard?

Tags: screen-capture

I have pressed Shift-Cmd-4 and selected an area. Now it is in screen capture app. But I need it inside clipboard to paste here. How to do that?

Comment: The steps are a little different over the time on macOS. Are you running Big Sur?

Comment: Cmd/shift/4 saves as a file, not to clipboard. See the linked question.

Comment: @bmike - has it changed again since Mojave? {i'm falling behind the times, I'm afraid]